# Processing multiple files in awk without "next" statement

Tags: bash, awk

My particular task is to arrange the lines in a file2 in a way it is in file1, where the number in the file1 should correspond the number in file2. My output files:

file1

```
23
4
75
19
```

file2

```
4 apple
19 mango
23 kiwi
75 orange
```

The desire output:

```
23 kiwi
4 apple
75 orange
19 mango
```

For now, I simply did it with bash, but I am particularly interested in a possibility of doing it in awk. I tried the following code `NR==FNR {a=$1} NR!=FNR {if ($1==a) print $0;next}' file1 file2`, but it didn't work.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: If it wasn't for the specific order, `join` would have been perfect

Comment: Why do you need it without `next`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try, with `next` statement

```
awk 'NR==FNR {d[$1]=$0; next} {print d[$1]}' file2 file1
```

without `next` statement

```
awk 'NR==FNR {d[$1]=$0} NR!=FNR{print d[$1]}' file2 file1
```

you get,

```
23 kiwi
4 apple
75 orange
19 mango
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason why you can't use `next` here. The logic is straight-forward, create the hash-map from `file2` and on `file1` for each record in `$1`, print out its hashed value.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{hash[$1]=$2; next}{print $1,hash[$1]}' file2 file1
23 kiwi
4 apple
75 orange
19 mango
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Inian. I wanted to use it without "next", because I thought that making an array would break the order and give the correct, but disordered answer.

Comment: @MirrG: Well `you thought` may be, but it is possible as in my answer right! So it is solving your problem?

Comment: Yes, of course, I  didn't think to just used hashed values.

Comment: @MirrG: Don't forget to mark it accepted! Thanks! and please update the question to remove the part without needing next

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **process** the files in order, i.e. **file1 before file2** and **not use next** then you can use this awk-script, file `fruits.awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk

{
    if(a1[$1]!=1)
        a1[$1]=a2[FNR][$1]=1;
    else{

        for(i in a2) {
            for(j in a2[i])
                if(j==$1)
                    a2[i][j]=$2;
        }
    }
}

END {
    for(i in a2) {
        for(j in a2[i])
            print j, a2[i][j];
    }
}
```

Use:

```
$awk -f fruits.awk file1 file2
23 kiwi
4 apple
75 orange
19 mango
```